# Run knitr code chunks in bookdown's pdf_book before_body

Tags: r, knitr, bookdown

In a [bookdown project](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown), is it possible to execute code chunks in the .tex/.Rnw files called in the `includes` section of the `_output.yml`?

My setup is the following:

```
# _output.yml:
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: header.tex
    before_body: front-matter.Rnw
    after_body: backmatter.tex
  engine:xelatex
```

In `front-matter.Rnw` I'd like to print some text from a code chunk that runs a bash command, say:

```
\begin{flushleft}
    Updated: \\
    <<updated, echo=FALSE, tidy=FALSE, results="asis", engine="bash">>=
    "git log -1 --format=%cd --date=format:'%d %B %Y' -- ../bookdown"
    @
\end{flushleft}
```

For a reason that I don't know, the output, after running Build Book (bookdown::pdf_book), from Rstudio, is not the expected date, but the command itself:

[image: sample output]

I will appreciate any suggestion!,

Thanks,
Mihai

Comment: The truncated output from the code chunk made me think of escaping some characters, such as `'` or `%`, but even a simpler `echo` command is printed the same: `«updated, echo=FALSE, tidy=FALSE, results=”asis”, engine=”bash”»= echo Hello @`